# in IOS , implement 9-patch image with strange white vertical line?

Tags: ios, swift, image

**Here is the case:**

- raw image:

> gift.9

[image: 0000]

- image after processing

there are two strange white vertical lines

[image: 22233]

- code part:

  ```
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        let imgViewWidth: CGFloat = 300
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 250), size: CGSize(width: imgViewWidth, height: 100)))
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        if let image = UIImage(named: "gift.9"), let img = stretch(image: image, newWidth: imgViewWidth){
            imgView.image = img
        }
  ```

the logic is easy , image crop and stretch.

**image crop**

```
       func crop(img: UIImage, with rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
            guard let cgImg = img.cgImage else { return nil }
            // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
            if let imageRef: CGImage = cgImg.cropping(to: rect){
                // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
                let image: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: img.scale, orientation: img.imageOrientation)
                return image
            }
            else{
                return nil
            }
        }
```

**image stretch**

```
func stretch(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        guard image.size.width < newWidth else {
            return image
        }

        let originalWidth = image.size.width
        let offset: CGFloat = 1
        // crop left first
        let left = crop(img: image, with: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: originalWidth/2, height: image.size.height))
        // crop right first
        let right = crop(img: image, with: CGRect(x: originalWidth/2, y: 0, width: originalWidth/2, height: image.size.height))

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: image.size.height),
                                               false, image.scale)

        let lhsResizable = left?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                                                                  left: originalWidth/2 - offset,
                                                                                  bottom: 0,
                                                                                  right: 0),
                                                  resizingMode: .stretch)
        // draw left stretched first
        lhsResizable?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth/2, height: image.size.height))
        
        let rhsResizable = right?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                                                                  left: 0,
                                                                                  bottom: 0,
                                                                                  right: originalWidth/2 - offset),
                                                  resizingMode: .stretch)
        // then , draw right stretched
        rhsResizable?.draw(in: CGRect(x: newWidth/2, y: 0, width: newWidth/2, height: image.size.height))

        let fullImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return fullImage
    }
```

*PS:*

I marked the two strange vertical white line

[image: 999999]

**How to get rid of it?**

Any other method is welcomed.

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment to go over your code in detail, but that looks like an off-by-one error where you have a single pixel gap between the left, middle, and right segments of your drawing. What if you set `offset = 0`?

Comment: `offset = 0` not works. I tried , and it is still there